# How to self-learn probabilities

Tags: probability, self-learning, finance, career-development

Bit of background: I’m 27, graduated 4 years ago with a bachelors in Computer Science in which I did well. Since I graduated, I’ve been working as an algo trader for a bank. I’d like to start applying for quant trading type jobs at hedge funds/market making firms, but the majority of them require some background in maths.

I’ve been looking at doing a Masters in Financial maths starting September 2025, so I’ve been myself a year to improve my maths, and if the master doesn’t pan out, at least I’d like to have stronger foundations in maths.

I’d say my maths are quite poor at the moment, my undergrad wasn’t math heavy at all.

I figured I’d start with probabilities, since it’s the topic I’m most interested in and having some understanding of it seems a requirement for the kind of job I’d like.

I’ve been following Harvard Stats110 from Joe Blitzstein, reading the book, following the EDX, watching the lectures, and doing practice problems. I do roughly 10-20 hours a week. But I’m starting slow down more and more on the book as the problems are becoming exponentially harder and new notation is introduced (probably because of my narrow math knowledge).

Wondering if anyone has advice, opinions on other approaches, anything really, as I’m structuring this on my own with not much support and don’t know if I’m using my time as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Blitzstein is a great choice and progressing slowly is often just how it goes when learning math. But you could also mix in some other textbooks like Ross’s book A First Course in Probability.